# Using two queries at the same time. PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

Okay so, I don't really know anything about PDO, my friend just asked me to post this here since he's not very good at English. Anyway, this is how he explained it to me:

The code provided is supposed to get a couple of values, save them, and it's supposed to get something out of another table with the help of the values gotten from earlier. The problem according to my friend is that it doesn't get the second value.

Code:

```
$user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT username,id,password FROM user WHERE email=:email");
$query->bindParam(':email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();
$user_username=$row['username'];
$user_group=$row['group'];   
$query_group = $db->prepare("SELECT color,name FROM group WHERE id=:id");
$query_group->bindParam(':id', $user_group, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query_group->execute();
$row = $query_group->fetch();
$group_color=$row['color'];
$group_name=$row['name'];
```

Comment: You could use a single query to get all the data with **`JOIN`**: `SELECT u.username,u.id,u.password,g.color,g.name FROM user u JOIN \`group\` g ON g.id=u.id WHERE u.email=:email` :) Keep in mind that `group` is a reserved word on MySQL and you must use backticks on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word `group` used as a table name needs to be enclosed in backticks. `group` is a reserved key word (`GROUP BY` clause).

```
SELECT 
    color, 
    name 
FROM `group`
WHERE id = :id
```

Using the above would work.

---

You can shorten the entire code by using a `JOIN` clause too. As [commented above by Prix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837482/using-two-queries-at-the-same-time-pdo/18837532#comment27790797_18837482), the code shall be:

```
$user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT 
    u.username,
    u.id,
    u.password,
    g.color,
    g.name
FROM user u
JOIN `group` g
    ON g.id = u.id
WHERE u.email = :email");
// I think emails are supposed to be `PDO::PARAM_STR`
$query->bindParam(':email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();
$user_username = $row['username'];
$group_color = $row['color'];
$group_name = $row['name'];
```

Comment: In OP's question : the second SELECT will not work there is no `group` in the first select statement. important for  `$query_group->bindParam(':id', $user_group, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: @moskito-x the second example would however work given that he needs to match the ids.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't have `group` in your select statement .**

If you don't use `*` in your select you must have the field name in your query .

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT username,id,password FROM user WHERE email=:email");
```

This query gives you only `username,id,password` back NOT the field `group` .

so try to use `$row['group']` is wrong .

```
$user_group=$row['group'];
```

So also put `group` in your select statement
Place also group in backticks it's a reserved word

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, `group` FROM user WHERE email=:email");
```

This is also a reason for important  variables (e.g for next query) to consider their validity.

```
if (isset($row['group'])) {
    database logic
   } else {
    error
   }
```

With this simple test you would have found the error itself.